# Saving 30 keys from an array to another variable

Tags: php, arrays, highcharts

I have a problem with my code sadly. So I have an array with around 100 keys saved into a $data variable that looks like this:

```
["data"]=>
  array(413) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#254 (7) {
      ["Date"]=>
      string(10) "2016-09-08"
      ["Open"]=>
      string(6) "771.00"
      ["Close"]=>
      string(6) "782.00"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#254 (7) {
      ["Date"]=>
      string(10) "2016-09-07"
      ["Open"]=>
      string(6) "71.00"
      ["Close"]=>
      string(6) "82.00"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#254 (7) {
      ["Date"]=>
      string(10) "2016-09-06"
      ["Open"]=>
      string(6) "571.00"
      ["Close"]=>
      string(6) "682.00"
    }
    [3]=>
    object(stdClass)#254 (7) {
      ["Date"]=>
      string(10) "2016-09-05"
      ["Open"]=>
      string(6) "781.00"
      ["Close"]=>
      string(6) "702.00"
    }
  }
```

I try to save the first 30  `["Close"]` keys, but I need to save them from the 30th to the first key, hence my for loop:

```
<?php

     $lowValue = [];
     for($i = 29; $i >= 0; $i--){
        foreach ($data->data[$i] as $obj) {
          if (isset($obj->Close)) {
             return $lowValue[] = $obj->Close;
          }
        }
     }

 ?>
 data: {!! json_encode(lowValue) !!}
```

The result I need to save with json_encode because I use it as data for a highchart. But I get an empty variable, any ideas why? And another question which I looked up on the internet but I get no answer to, can I use json_encode for functions as well? Meaning if I want to make a function can I use that as a parameter? Thank you very much for your time, any help is welcomed!
After I've modified the code:
data:

```
                  <?php
                    $lowValue = [];
                    foreach ($data->data as $obj) {
                        if (isset($obj->Close)) {
                            // add the element to the beginning of the array
                            array_unshift($lowValue, $obj->Close);
                        }

                        if(count($lowValue) >= 30) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    echo json_encode($lowValue);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$lowValue = [];
foreach ($data->data[$i] as $obj) {
    if (isset($obj->Close)) {
        // add the element to the beginning of the array
        array_unshift($lowValue, $obj->Close);
    }

    if(count($lowValue) >= 30) {
        break;
    }
}

echo json_encode(['data' => $lowValue]);
```

Regarding your second question you should create another question on SO.

Comment: After I've worked a bit on it, I got results, but I still encounter a problem. In highcarts the result should look like this: data: [22, 335, 11, 7547], instead the numbers I have in that array are of this format: data: ["22", "335"]. I have to make them not be strings anymore. I will edit my question with how my code looks like now.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

With @mapek 's help and after I've worked a bit on his example the solution in my case was:

```
data:<?php
       $lowValue = [];
       foreach ($data->data as $obj) {
          if (isset($obj->Close)) {
              // add the element to the beginning of the array
              array_unshift($lowValue, $obj->Close);
          }

          if(count($lowValue) >= 30) {
                   break;
          }
       }
       $low = array_map( create_function('$value', 'return (int)$value;'),
                                    $lowValue);
       echo json_encode($low);
                ?>
```

Which displays my array like this: `data:[621, 512, 578]`...